# What is the material and how to seal it?

Tags: ceiling, paint, sealant

As you can see In the photo the layer (*paint?*) on my bathroom ceiling has fallen off.

1. I think the red/brownish colour part is off-gassing a smell.  Does anybody know what material this is and be what it is off-gassing exactly?
2. How do I seal this smell in?  Will any paint work/reduce it to negligible levels or does this material/ceiling require some sort of purpose built sealant (*is that the thing that’s coming off?*).
3. Once the paint or sealant has been applied, generally speaking how long before most of the smell will go?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Test it for lead and scrape/peel it off before applying new paint. The issue happened due to too much moisture (humidity). Solve the humidity problem and you shouldn't encounter this issue again.

Comment: For sealing in odors you can do a search on this site for shellac, there are   questions on odor and  answers for using shellac to seal. Shellac then paint.

Comment: @Alaska Man if I apply shellac and leave it will that be sufficient.  If the shellac seals it in and the shellac itself doesn’t gas off more than paint does I’d rather leave it just with the shellac.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The painted coating (it looks to be at least the most recent coat of paint and an additional layer below, of either paint or primer) has obviously failed. The cause of the failure is *most likely* inadequate surface preparation prior to application, exacerbated by high-humidity conditions.

It is **very unlikely** that the ceiling plaster itself is "off-gassing" or that it is, in and of itself, the cause of any odor. What is likely is that the odor is mildew growth, of which there are some tell-tale signs of along the edge of the wall.

You need to:

- strip **all** unsound material
- chemically kill all mildew (there are various methods; I use dilute bleach
- sand the entire substrate (while also patching any gaps and defects such as the linear crack where the wall meets the ceiling)
- clean/wash the entire area
- properly prime and paint using high quality paint products and professional grade applicators

NOTE- a special bonding primer (e.g. shellac) is not necessary if you prep the job as described.

NOTE- a paint with a *sheen*, such as gloss or semi-gloss, would tend to resist problems associated with moisture better than flat paints.

NOTE- pro-grade applicators and high-quality paints result in a better looking, better performing, and easier job.

NOTE- for longevity and bio-growth prevention, you should ensure there is adequate ventilation. Now is the time to consider upgrading your exhaust fan.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  My only pickle is that the odour doesn’t smell like mildew at all.  I sniffed and it takes me to the browny area while the small amounts of mould are still on the surface paint.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is coming from above?**

Is it possible water (or something) is coming down from above?  Those white rings look like something wet has come thru and dried, leaving behind what was dissolved in the water.  I am sad to say that I have seen those rings on my bathroom ceiling from leaky toilets one floor above.  Mine did not have white stuff though.

If water is coming from above there might be more serious problems deeper and that is what you are smelling.  Dried urine leaves white rings.  Rat urine does not smell like mildew.  I hope that is not the case.

Comment: If I just clean the white rings up could this remove the odour? Also could the leak/urine you have cited be the cause for the peeling in the first place?  Thanks

Comment: Whatever caused that peeling has been going on for a long time and it involves moisture.  My guess is white rings and peeling is related.   If it is coming from moisture inside the bathroom it will be obvious to you.  If it is coming from a space above the bathroom you will need to find out what is going on in that space, because you want it to stop!

Comment: Re cleaning it up to remove odoro - if you have a ceiling element soaked with animal urine to the point where the paint peels off, that ceiling element will have to be replaced.